# Why spark always uses a single core on my PC?

Tags: python, linux, scala, bigdata, apache-spark

Even when I give a parameter to the `groupByKey` function, for example `groupByKey(4)`, when I check with the top command, spark is still using one core. I run my script like that.

```
spark-submit --master local[4] program.py
```

So, why spark only uses one core when I tell it to use 4?

Comment: There seem to me to be two possibilities a) spark has a bug b) something about your program prevents parallelism. The first is a bit unlikely given you're not calling it in any unusual way. The second is impossible to help with unless you post your code!

Comment: Also, from the documentation for groupByKey: "Note: By default, the level of parallelism in the output depends on the number of partitions of the parent RDD. You can pass an optional numTasks argument to set a different number of tasks.".

Comment: @Paul: I just use mapPartitions and then call groupByKey over it. I think you are right, maybe I have just one partition. Is there any function to divide one partition into a number of partitions?

Comment: I don't know the first thing about Spark, but I do know how to search the programming guide: "repartition(numPartitions) Reshuffle the data in the RDD randomly to create either more or fewer partitions and balance it across them. This always shuffles all data over the network." (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html)

Answer (score 2):

You're running this on Linux, if the tags to your question are to be trusted. Under linux, top does not, by default, show every thread (it shows every process). `local[4]` tells spark to work locally on 4 threads (not processes).

Run `top -H` to pick up the threads.